# Is it possible run sonicwall vpn client as service?

Tags: vpn, winlogon

I have a win2008 R2 server with IIS, some sites connect to database with a sonic wall vpn client.

So, when the server is rebooeted soniclwall vpn client starts after login olny...

When the server is rebooted I need vpn starts before logon...

some idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard args to create a scheduled startup or an automatically execution:
https://support.software.dell.com/download/downloads?id=5411235

There is also an option that allow you to starts GVC at the login:

> Start this program when I log in - Launches the Dell SonicWALL Global VPN Client when 
>   you log into your computer.